# How to remove and set border color of a widget (FloatigSearchView)? Specifically the bottom border color

Tags: java, android, xml, floating

I imported floatingsearchview into my app and I can't change the bottom border color and remove other borders. At this point it looks like this 
[image]

I'm trying to get it to work like on the example below 
[image]

Link to the lib: https ://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview

Xml code of the widget:

```
<com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView
        android:id="@+id/floating_search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/color_title_en"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:floatingSearch_actionMenuOverflowColor="@color/color_primary_red"
        app:floatingSearch_clearBtnColor="@color/color_primary_red"
        app:floatingSearch_close_search_on_keyboard_dismiss="true"
        app:floatingSearch_dimBackground="false"
        app:floatingSearch_dismissOnOutsideTouch="true"
        app:floatingSearch_dividerColor="@color/color_primary_red"
        app:floatingSearch_leftActionColor="@color/color_primary_red"
        app:floatingSearch_leftActionMode="noLeftAction"
        app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginLeft="@dimen/search_view_inset"
        app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginRight="@dimen/search_view_inset"
        app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginTop="@dimen/search_view_inset"
        app:floatingSearch_searchHint="@string/search_hint"
        app:floatingSearch_showSearchKey="true"
        app:floatingSearch_suggestionsListAnimDuration="150"
        app:floatingSearch_backgroundColor="@color/transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview/issues/152) on the repository asks the same question. It seems there is no official way, however there are some hacky methods used to solve the issue.

1) Add this in your XML code

```
app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginLeft="-5dp"
app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginRight="-5dp"
app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginTop="-5dp"
```

2)Add the following line in the Java class.

```
mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.search_query_section).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!